# A Monitor D-sub port and a PC VGA port and DVR VGA port

Tags: display, vga, dvr

I'm going to install two cameras in my office. I have a PC in my room that is supposed to connect DVR to its monitor. But I have a big problem; although that DVR have HDMI and VGA port, my monitor does have one D-sub port so that I have one choice; connecting monitor to DVR or to PC. The expert said me that KVM switch is only solution albeit I can not use both Camera and PC in one time.

So my question is there another way to use those together?

Answer (score 0):

VGA capture card which would let you view DVR in real time inside your operating system.

Comment: I couldn't understand  exactly what u said.VGA capture card is the same graphic card?

Comment: @Hamid No, you're looking for something that can get picture from VGA port, for example: https://www.amazon.com/VGA2USB-Video-Grabber-Capture-Device/dp/B000UO94DU (this is not a recomendation to buy this specific product, just first result from Google).

Comment: tnx. The Firewire card is useful for me?

Comment: I should connect DVR using AV to Capture card and monitor by VGA to Motherboard?

Comment: @Hamid yes, VGA to motherboard and DVR to capture card. Make sure that whatever capture card you choose can display picture from VGA input in real time. I'm not sure what you asking about FireWire.

Comment: Tnx again. How can i ensure that capture card is able to display pic from vga in real time? What does mean the "real time"?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?  Just mentioning a type of hardware isn't really an actionable solution to the question.  Just a helpful hint might be more appropriate as a comment.  Thanks.